# How to replace math equations in Visual Studio 2017 IDE?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-optimization, code-readability

I have a simple question. Is there an addon and/or built-in function in visual studio which can replace long (constant) equations with their fixed value?

For example:

```
int test = 123;
std::cout << 1 + (11 * 10) + test << std::endl;
```

Should be:

```
int test = 123;
std::cout << 111 + test << std::endl;
```

I know this could be changed manually but I have a lot of code I have to apply this to with a lot of decimals, and it would take weeks to do it manually. Also sorry if the question was asked before, I personally didn't find anything.

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to change the code?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have written the code a long time ago, put in a lot of unnecessary equations and even though it is compiling it is very hard to read.

Comment: Do you want it to handle `const` values and/or `#define`s too? If not, it would be possible to design a plugin that uses a regex to search for simple constant equations and then evaluate it. If so, though, you'd probably need to write a compiler module...

Comment: Even if you could it isn't what you really want, in all likelihood. Consider `days = 3600 * 24 * 7 * 52 / 2` What you'd really want is symbolic values like `days = hour_seconds * day_hours * week_days * year_weeks / 2` Or something.

Comment: @Ken Y-N I do not want it to handle defines and constant variables preferably. Just the numbers mixed with them.

Comment: @ZanLynx I do not need variables. My code is something like:   `back.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(160 * 2, 90 * 11));
play.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(160 * 5, 90 * 11));
name.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(160 * 1.5f, 90 * 1.2f + settings.screenWidth()/2));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the guys wondering how I resolved this problem. I installed Visual Studio Code and an extension called Calculate from Andrew Carreiro https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=acarreiro.calculate , which can calculate and replace expressions for me.

Comment: Let this perhaps be a lesson about using magic numbers everywhere.